# transfer multiple users directories to Onedrive for Business

Tags: office365, onedrive

I'm in the process of migrated my users to O365 and was wondering if there was a simple way of transferring all the users personal file shares to their one-drive for business account. I would like to automate this process. There are 40 users that i would like automate. Size ranging from a few KB to a few GB.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for migrating files from user home directories to OneDrive for Business is to use a third party migration tool like Files To Go. Files To Go has dedicated support for bulk [migrating user home directories to OneDrive for Business](http://www.thinkscape.com/SharePoint-Online-File-Migration-Tool/). Files To Go has been used successfully to migrate many terabytes of data to OneDrive for Business.

Disclaimer; I work for the company that develops Files To Go.